# Item Edit Form: Delete Item on "Cancel"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-form, delete

I am building a custom list item edit form using SharePoint Designer.

I need the item to be deleted when user clicks "Cancel" button (same functionality as he would press "Delete" in ribbon).

I couldn't find too much information about it, so I tried to copy the code of "Delete" button in ribbon and replace the "Cancel" button with it, but it doesn't work...

Any suggestions? Anything helps.

**UPDATE:**

Code of the "Delete" button in the ribbon:

```
<a class="ms-cui-ctl-large" id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.DeleteItem-Large" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" mscui:controltype="Button" aria-describedby="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.DeleteItem_ToolTip" role="button" unselectable="on">
    <span class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer" unselectable="on">
        <span class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float ms-cui-imageDisabled" unselectable="on">
            <img class="" style="top: -341px;left: -511px;" unselectable="on" src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=43">
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" unselectable="on">
        Delete<br>Item
    </span>
</a>
```

Code of the "Cancel" button:

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl40$g_f25929d1_2f2f_439b_b216_92762649c491$gobackbutton2$ctl00$diidIOGoBack" value="Cancel" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.frameElement.cancelPopUp();}, 0); return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl40$g_f25929d1_2f2f_439b_b216_92762649c491$gobackbutton2$ctl00$diidIOGoBack&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_f25929d1_2f2f_439b_b216_92762649c491_gobackbutton2_ctl00_diidIOGoBack" accesskey="C" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" target="_self">
```

Basically, I'm hiding the whole ribbon row and want to have "Delete" button at the bottom of the form instead of "Cancel". But If I just copy the code, it doesn't work...

Comment: can you please share the code of cancel button?

Comment: @Hardik , see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below steps

1. Add ID field in Form

   ```
    <td> ID </td> <td id="txtID"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></td>
   ```
2. Add Delete button to the Form

   ```
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:CustomDelete()" value="Delete"></input>
   ```
3. Add the below code to Javascript of Form

   ```
   function CustomDelete()
   {
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); //gets the current context
   var web = context.get_web(); //gets the web object
   var list = web.get_lists(); //gets the collection of lists
   var targetList;

   targetList = list.getByTitle("MyCustomList");
   context.load(targetList);
   var itemId = document.getElementById("txtID").value;
   alert(itemId);
   var itemToDelete = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
   itemToDelete.deleteObject();
   targetList.update();
   context.executeQueryAsync(deleteItemSuccess, deleteItemFailed);
   }
   function deleteItemSuccess() {
   var listItemInfo = 'Item deleted: ';
   alert(listItemInfo);
   }
   function deleteItemFailed(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }
   ```

Reference :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/delete-an-item-in-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-javas/

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exactly what I was looking for... If I would use my custom js function, where do I place my javascript on the form?

Comment: You could place it above the div tag inside <ContentTemplate> tag of <SharePointVersionedContent>

Comment: I've placed my javascript into the form, but when I try to call my function with a button, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined".

Comment: Sorry, I had a syntax mistake in my function, I resolved it. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below `<a>` tag to work. Place below mentioned code to your Custom Edit Form & it will work.

```
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__delete={ID=',@ID,'};__commit'))}"><img border="0" alt="Edit" src="/_layouts/images/delete.gif" /></a>
```

Above Code is getting `@ID` from the URL as it defined the parameter available in QueryString.

I had tried this & it is working fine for me. :)

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" this way... I'm using SharePoint Online if that helps.

Comment: I had done the same in SharePoint online. I had created new EditForm & Made it default & than after i replaced Save and cancel buttons above the form with this line.